# Sliding Gabor Filter in python

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

Taken from the gabor filter example from skimage calculating a gabor filter for an image is easy:

```
import numpy as np

from scipy import ndimage as nd

from skimage import data
from skimage.util import img_as_float
from skimage.filter import gabor_kernel

brick = img_as_float(data.load('brick.png'))

kernel = np.real(gabor_kernel(0.15, theta = 0.5 * np.pi,sigma_x=5, sigma_y=5))

filtered = nd.convolve(brick, kernel, mode='reflect')

mean = filtered.mean()
variance = filtered.var()
```

brick is simply a numpy array. Suppose I have a 5000*5000 numpy array. What I want to achieve is to generate two new 5000*5000 numpy arrays where the pixels are the mean and var values of the gabor filter of the 15*15 window centered on them.

Could anyone help me achieve this?

**EDIT**

¿Why did I get downvoted? Anyway, to clarify I show an example on how to calculate a gabor filter on a single image. I would like to simply calculate a gabor filter on small square subsets of a very large image (hence the sliding window).

Comment: Could you clarify a bit by what you mean by "the mean and var values of the gabor filter..." The filter seems to be a 31x31 pixel linear filter. Would you like to have the rolling mean and average under this are (31x31) or the rolling mean and variance of the filtered image?

Answer (score 2):

There no standard methods to do this (that I know of), but you can do it yourself directly.

Each pixel in the convolution is the sum of the values of the shift gabor filter times the image pixels.  That is, each pixel in the convolution is basically the **mean** to within a constant normalization factor, so `filtered` is basically your mean.

The **variance** is a bit more difficult since that is the sum of the squares, and of course, you need to calculate the sqaures before you calculate the sums.  But, you can do this easy enough by pre-squaring both the image and the kernel, that is:

```
N = kernel.shape[0]*kernel.shape[1]
mean = nd.convolve(brick, kernel, mode='reflect')/N
var = nd.convolve(brick*brick, kernel*kernel, mode='reflect')/N - mean*mean
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to calculate the sliding average of an image (convolution with a square kernel with all 1's), the fast method is:

```
# fsize is the filter size in pixels
# integrate in the X direction
r_sum = numpy.sum(img[:, :fsize], axis=1)
r_diff =  img[:, fsize:] - img[:, :-fsize]
r_int = numpy.cumsum(numpy.hstack((r_sum.reshape(-1,1), r_diff)), axis=1)

# integrate in the Y direction
c_sum = numpy.sum(r_img[:fsize, :], axis=0)
c_diff = r_img[fsize:, :] - r_img[:-fsize, :]
c_int = numpy.cumsum(numpy.vstack((c_sum, c_diff)), axis=0)

# now we have an array of sums, average can be obtained by division
avg_img = c_int / (f_size * f_size)
```

This method returns an image which is size-1 pixels smaller in both directions, so you'll have to take care of border effects yourself. The edge most pixels are bad anyway, but it is up to you to choose the correct border fill, if you need one. The algorithm is the fastest way to obtain the mean (fewest calculations), especially much faster than `numpy.convolve`.

Similar trickery can be used in calculating the variance, if both the image and its square are averaged as above. Then

```
npts = fsize * fsize
variance = (rolling_sum(img**2) - rolling_sum(img)/npts) / npts
```

where `rolling_sum` is a sliding sum (i.e. the algorithm above without the last division). So, only two rolling sums (image and its square) are required to calculate the rolling variance.

(Warning: the code above is untested, it is there just to illustrate the idea.)